# Textarea enable Autocorrect

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, jquery-mobile, cordova, autocorrect

I'm having a small problem with autocorrect on an iPhone app I'm making using phonegap and jQuery mobile. I have a few  fields but it seems no matter what I do they wont autocorrect of autocapitalize.

what I have tried:

autocorrect='on' on textarea element (my understanding is that the default behaviour is on anyway)

autocorrect='on' on the form tags that wraps this textarea.

also tried some stuff with autocomplete and autocapitalize

I have checked on a few devices, all that correct properly in other UIwebview situations, and also on the emulator.

is it possibly because I am adding these form dynamically? or possibly because of jQuery mobile and a bug with dismissing autocorrect suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the JQuery Mobile js-file you will find that JQuery Mobile automatically sets autocorrect = "off" on all input fields.

It is a "Temporary workaround for issue 785" since the Autocorrect popup can't be dismissed by the user.

To use Autocorrect you will have to manipulate the JQuery Mobile js-file.